# Attempting to set up dual boot of Linux Mint 20.2 on MacBook Pro, but GRUB fails to install

Tags: multi-boot, grub, linux-mint, macbook

My work recently gave me a new MacBook Pro to use.  Since my last experience with Macs was in 1997 when I was 10 years old, I quickly decided to set up the MacBook to dual boot Linux Mint, as that's what I use at home.

Following several tutorials on the internet, I successfully disabled SIP, installed REFind, created the necessary partitions, and booted into Linux Mint from the live USB.

However, when I attempted to install Linux Mint on the partition, it failed, saying that it couldn't install GRUB on the designated EFI partition (no reason was given). This in turn caused the installer itself to crash.

Upon reboot, REfind gives me an option to boot from EFI, which launches GRUB, but it can't determine the boot order, and therefore doesn't actually book Linux, just hangs around in the minimal command line mode of GRUB forever.

How do I actually get it to fully install GRUB and/or actually run Linux Mint?

Thanks!

Comment: Knowing precisely which Mac would help - so we know at least if you're Intel or M1. BTW, macOS has improved a bit since System 7 ;))

Comment: It's a MacBook Pro, it's new enough that it only has USB-C ports, and it was running Big Sur before I bricked it. Unfortunately, that is the extent of my knowledge